# Start new activity but with the same class name as previous one

Tags: android, android-activity

I've been trying to find the solution for the following problem, but with no success:
I have an activity class that is showing web pages(presentation) which need to be logged (what user entered, duration, etc.). On some pages there are buttons which should open new presentation. 
Calling activity - CLMWebView.class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CLMWebView.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Between those lines of code are some intent.putExtra which are, I belive, not relevant for this.
As you can see, I am trying to start new activity with the same class as the calling activity. However, nothing happens. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Android manifest for CLMWebView.class

```
<activity android:name="com.msoft.views.CLMWebView"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard" 
    android:icon="@drawable/svicon" 
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: What launch mode of the activity in your manifest?

Comment: why would you want to do that ? why not just change the views ?

Comment: @njzk2 because it was easier for me just to open the new activity with the same functionality as the previous one. Plus, every opened presentation can have linked buttons to other presentation...But, your idea is definately worth thinking about if there is no solution for my problem

Comment: i don't see how that could be easier to open a new but identical activity. just put all the init stuff (including the setcontentview) in an init method, and call it when you want to restart you activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`singleTop` activity, visible, and in same task is not recreated.

Quoting the official docs:

> Similarly, a new instance of a "singleTop" activity may also be
>   created to handle a new intent. However, if the target task already
>   has an existing instance of the activity at the top of its stack, that
>   instance will receive the new intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a new
>   instance is not created. In other circumstances — for example, if an
>   existing instance of the "singleTop" activity is in the target task,
>   but not at the top of the stack, or if it's at the top of a stack, but
>   not in the target task — a new instance would be created and pushed on
>   the stack.

A better alternative will be to place the functionality in a fragment, and add a new fragment to back stack each time.

Comment: Thanks, this is it. Thanks to all of you for replying. Pretty stupid mistake, though...